# Is there a json object that gets returned on the web-to-lead submit?

Tags: json, ajax, web2lead

Using slightly custom web-to-lead form and thinking about using ajax to send the data and wait for a response json object.

Is there any object that gets returned? The main idea was:

```
function submitForm() {
        var contactForm = $(this);
            $.ajax( {
          url: contactForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
          type: contactForm.attr( 'method' ),
          data: contactForm,
          success: submitFinished
        } );
    return false;
}
```

And then catch the success:

```
function submitFinished( response ) {
        response = $.trim( response );
            if ( response == "success" ) {
                //do success stuff
            } else {
                //do error stuff
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying a tool like Fiddler and see what is returned. Normally, you get redirected so I'd expect a HTTP 301 response.

Comment: I usally do, but first I look into the stack and do something else. Maybe someone tried it already and knows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately - this will be tricky on two counts:

1. Salesforce do not serve [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers and browsers will abort the request with `XMLHttpRequest ... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
2. The visitor never knows if WebToLead fails. Say a validation rule prevents the upsert, you will receive a failure email but your visitor (or curl proxy) will still get 200 OK with the return URL.

This HTTP header may present on the response if the submission is really botched (eg no Org ID):

```
is-processed: true Exception:common.exception.SalesforceGenericException
```

But [the response](http://apikitchen.com/#Hgh7f) is always `200 OK`, with the following `text/html` body:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=retURL" />
  </head>
  <script>
    if (window.location.replace){ 
      window.location.replace('retURL');
    } else {;
      window.location.href ='retURL';
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

You might be more confident about doing this with AJAX if you implement a server-side submission from your webserver as [explored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591438/salesforce-success-handler-for-ajax-call) [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339550/how-can-i-get-jquery-post-to-work-with-a-salesforce-webtolead).

Comment: Validation rules run on WebToLead - http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_validation_considerations.htm

Comment: Ouch, I've updated the answer so as not to mislead - thanks @MikeChale

Comment: No problem; I just happen to remember that because I get automated emails saying why the W2L couldn't be added.

Answer (score 1):

you can use REST API of sfdc to do this .  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_create.htm

A javascript library called forceTK is available @       https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit

An example on how to use this on Account is shown below.You can modify easily for lead object with an integration user credential.

```
<html>
  <head>

<!-- 
jQuery - http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.js"></script>
<!--
From jQuery-swip - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-swip/source/browse/trunk/jquery.popupWindow.js 
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery.popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="forcetk.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // OAuth Configuration
    var loginUrl    = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
    var clientId    = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
    var redirectUri = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_APP/oauthcallback.html';
    var proxyUrl    = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_APP/proxy.php?mode=native';

    var client = new forcetk.Client(clientId, loginUrl, proxyUrl);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#message').popupWindow({ 
            windowURL: getAuthorizeUrl(loginUrl, clientId, redirectUri),
            windowName: 'Connect',
            centerBrowser: 1,
            height:524, 
            width:675
        });
    });

    function getAuthorizeUrl(loginUrl, clientId, redirectUri){
        return loginUrl+'services/oauth2/authorize?display=popup'
            +'&response_type=token&client_id='+escape(clientId)
            +'&redirect_uri='+escape(redirectUri);
    }

    function sessionCallback(oauthResponse) {
        if (typeof oauthResponse === 'undefined'
            || typeof oauthResponse['access_token'] === 'undefined') {
            $('#message').html('Error - unauthorized!');
        } else {
            client.setSessionToken(oauthResponse.access_token, null,
                oauthResponse.instance_url);

                client.query("SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1", 
                  function(response){
                    $('#message').html('The first account I see is '
                      +response.records[0].Name);
                });
        }
    }
</script>
<p id="message">Click here.</p>
```

Comment: How about a [public REST API](http://www.wadewegner.com/2013/03/creating-anonymous-rest-apis-with-salesforce-com/)?

Comment: @user320 Excellent idea that can be done but i think a public custom REST apex  wrapper class will be needed to do